# Scala: Random List of Val Order

Tags: list, scala, random, shuffle

I have some of `val` that should randomly coming to list of result. Here's the code:

```
def motivation(name:String, score:Int){
val quote1 = "You're not lost. You're locationally challenged." //score=10
val quote2 = "Time is the most valuable thing a man can spend." //score=20
val quote3 = "At times one remains faithful to a cause." //score=10
val quote4 = "Only because its opponents do not cease to be insipid." //score=10
val quote5 = "Life can be complicated." //score=20

case Some(score) => val quoteRes = shufle(????)
}
```

1. How do I marked score of each quotes so it will be able to calculated.
2. How do I randomly pick the quotes based of `score` of name and do the `shuffle` the order also?

for example if John(name) has 40(score) the result could be quotes2+quotes3+quotes4 or quotes4+quotes5 or quotes1+quotes2+quotes5

Comment: I think it'll be better to have pairs of (score, quote). The rest part of this question is algorithm things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess I'd be likely to start with all the quotes and their respective scores.

```
val quotes = Map( "quote this" -> 10
                , "no quote" -> 20
                , "quoteless" -> 10
                )
```

Then combine them in as many ways as possible.

```
// all possible quote combinations
val qCombos = (1 to quotes.size).flatMap(quotes.keys.toList.combinations)
```

Turn that into a `Map` keyed by their respective score sums.

```
// associate all quote combinations with their score total
val scoreSum = qCombos.groupBy(_.map(quotes).sum)
```

Now you call look up all the quotes that, when combined, sum to a given amount.

```
// get all the quote combinations that have this score total
scoreSum(20) 
//res0: IndexedSeq[List[String]] = Vector(List(no quote), List(quote this, quoteless))
```

As for presenting the results in a random order, since you've already asked about that [twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39990858/shuffle-a-list-in-scala) [already](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39981539/scala-random-string), and gotten good answers, I'll assume that's not going to be a problem.

Comment: This is the most valuable things in my life, brother! thank you. You completed all my problems with random and shuffle things. As php programmer, this is something new for me. But many problems will coming tomorrow, should I create this apps with java? since java has big communities and tutorials, many people said scala is more simple than java. What do you think?