# Shuffle a List in Scala

Tags: list, scala, shuffle, shift

I have question to for shuffle list in scala using `scala.util.Random`.

For example I have

```
val a = cyan
val b = magenta
val c = yellow
val d = key

val color = Random.shuffle.List(a,b,c,d).toString //but it doesn't work ;(
```

so I want the `val color` to be random order of `val a, b, c and d`.

Comment: You've asked basically the same question three times now.  Are you not getting the answers you need? (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39989771/scala-random-list-of-val-order, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39981539/scala-random-string)

Comment: Instead of shuffle.List(a,b,c,d) the right thing is shuffle(List(a,b,c,d))

Answer (score 68, accepted):

User Scala's Random class method shuffle:

```
scala.util.Random.shuffle(List(a,b,c,d))
```